# Evaluate $\iiint_{V} (2x+1) \, dx\,dy\,dz$ in spherical coord. where $V = \lbrace x^2+y^2 \leq 9 \mid 0 \leq z\leq y, \ \ y \geq 0\rbrace$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, coordinate-systems

I am asked the following problem:

> Evaluate the integral $$\iiint_{V} (2x+1) \, dx\,dy\,dz$$ in spherical coordinates given that $V$ is the region defined by: $$V = \lbrace x^2+y^2 \leq 9 \mid  0 \leq z\leq y, \ \  y \geq 0\rbrace.$$

What I have so far is

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{3 \csc(\theta) \csc(\phi)} (2\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)+1) \cdot \rho^2 \sin(\phi) \, d \rho\, d \phi\, d \theta$$

which makes perfect sense to me. What am I getting wrong?

**Textbook's final answer: $18$**

Thank you.

Comment: Why complicate things? Integrating with respect to $z$ shows your integral is $$\iint_W(2x+1)ydxdy$$ where $W$ is the half disk $$W=\{x^2+y^2\leqslant9,y\geqslant0\}$$ Now, *polar* coordinates are $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ and the integral is $$\int_0^\pi\int_0^3(2r\cos\theta+1)(r\sin\theta)\,rdr\,d\theta$$ which you should be able to compute.

Comment: @Did: even faster: $$\iiint_{V}2x\,dx\,dy\,dz = 0$$ by symmetry and $$\iiint_{V} 1\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ is just the volume of $V$, that can be computed through elementary geometry.

Comment: Thank you for the input guys but the challenge is exactly that: do it with spherical coordinates.